# Generating ids for divs in Vue.JS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

Consider the Bootstrap Accordion:

```
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <div data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
       i'm not collapsed
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="card-block">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
        on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
        raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

      </div>
```

I would like to dynamically generated the cards in it with vue so I can add this line on card:

```
  <div class="card" v-for="x in response">
```

and it will generate a card for each of them. However, the are all referencing the same id for collapsing so only one of them opens/closes.

To solve this, I tried to change the id to change these lines:

```
  <div class="card" v-for="(x,index) in response">

 <div id="{{index}}" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
```

but this doesn't compile. I can't think of any other approaches for this. I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use interpolation in attributes, use binding instead

```
<div class="card" v-for="(x,index) in response">
  <div :id="index" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne"></div>
</div>
```